# Neck getting tired in across bench dumbbell pull over

Tags: dumbbells

> [image]

I'm trying to do the pull over variant like in the above pic, and one issue I have is, when doing it, I feel my neck is getting exhausted faster than anything else. Am I doing something wrong or is this a part of the lift?